# Precise bouncing on walls?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

Can someone teach me how to set up a object that simple moves foward and baunces in reflection whenever it hit a wall. much like a bilhar ball or the green shells from Mario Kart. 
I tried using softbody physics with elasticity but it is too buggy especially in fast moving objects, I need precise mirror reflected baunces.

Maybe with a script that captures the normal of the wall and the angle of the object. It's much like a specular vector in the pic, but instead of the light I need to make this with the object's tragetory.
 Unfortunately I don't know programming. Help?[image: specular vector]

Comment: You mean a [rigid body simulation?](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/)

Comment: no, your link is not related with my question, I told, using the physics simulation is buggy for making objects baunce precisely specially in high speeds. and it's heavy too. what I need is a Ray vector to calculate the rotation to apply based in the angle of the colision with the wall.

Comment: Softbodies and rigidbodies are two different things. If you are instead trying to build your own physics engine, you will need a strong programming background...

Comment: Both soft And rigid body doenst offer me a solution for this, like i said its imprecise for what a am triyng to do. The most simple solution thar ive came out is simple rotating The objetc when it hit The wall, ive done a logic setup thase reproduces fake baunces, rotating the object to opposite side of the wall, that works fine, way better than using the dynamic physics. the thing is: it is possible to get the wall normal from a Ray sensor on front of the object to calculate how many rotation to apply. it's simple I am not building a whole new physics engine.

Comment: How precise do you need? If you use rigid body and just enable the elasticity coefficient, you get pretty accurate results. (Soft body is just terrible though).

Comment: O told, in high speeds the dynamic physics don't work. My object is a projectile, with physics it bounces near randomly and bounces upwards too. 
I have a logic set up movement not based in physics just in coordinates. (simple motion actuator) (not using linear velocity) just simple move forward, hit the wall, rotate horizontally and continues... it fake well the bounce, all that I need is to get the wall angle to tell the projectile how many degrees to rotate horizontally (Z axis)